# How to solve for all vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ where all points are integers (n-dimensional Diophantine General Solver)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, permutations

Looking for a Method of obtaining all points in an $n$-dimensional vector space. This is for a computer application.

For example: I have a plane described by $8x + 5y + 2z = 14$, where $x,y,z \geq 0$.

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+8x+%2B+5y+%2B+2z+%3D+14,+x%3E%3D0,+y%3E%3D0,+z%3E%3D0) is a Wolfram Link to this plot.

So on this plane I want to find all values of $(x,y,z)$ where $x,y$ and $z$ are all integers, or floor($x$), floor($y$), floor($z$).

In this example there are only $3$ dimensions, but I would like to go higher without having to cycle through all combinations.

The most comprehensive solution I can come up with computationally so far is to permutate through all the possible integer values, but I'm not $100\%$ happy with that solution... because for a high-dimensional problem, the computation intensifies. I'd like a solution where computation is not bound to dimensionality or scaling factors.

**Edit**

Lee said: I think you are saying that you want to find all triples of non-negative integers (l,m,n)(l,m,n) which satisfy one of the following two properties: either 8l+5m+2n=158l+5m+2n=15; or there exists a triple of real numbers (x,y,z)(x,y,z) such that 8x+5m+2n=148x+5m+2n=14, and such that l=floor(x)l=floor(x), m=floor(y)m=floor(y), n=floor(z)n=floor(z).

This is a correct interpretation. However, this is not limited to a 3-dimensional space. I am looking for a general function / method that will ingest coefficients of a linear equation and solve for all vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the notation edit @Sahiba

Comment: It's called a diophantine equation. Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want to find. I think you are saying that you want to find all triples of non-negative integers $(l,m,n)$ which satisfy one of the following two properties: either $8l+5m+2n=15$; or there exists a triple of real numbers $(x,y,z)$ such that $8x+5m+2n=14$, and such that $l=\text{floor}(x)$, $m=\text{floor}(y)$, $n=\text{floor}(z)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks. Reading down the page it recommends solving a linear Diopahntine equation by computing it's 'Smith Normal Form' : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Comment: Yes correct @LeeMosher, I would like to write a general function that will ingest the coefficients and output all solutions for the linear equation.

Comment: You might want to edit that correction into your answer, because others might be confused by the same thing that confused me, but they might not see the correction in the comments.

Comment: Generally, Parametrization is what you need.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan After much reading, I found that there is no general solution or algorithm for Diophantine beyond first-order. Here's my sad proof: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html

Comment: @Wuestenfux Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: Are you assuming the coefficients are nonnegative integers? If negative coefficients are allowed, the number of solutions can be infinite. Trivial example: $2x - y = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the number of solutions to *n*-variable linear equation then you can use this approach:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int countSol(int coeff[], int start, int end, int rhs)
{ 
    // Base case
    if (rhs == 0)
       return 1;

    int result = 0;  

    for (int i=start; i<=end; i++)
      if (coeff[i] <= rhs)
        if((coeff[i]) < 0){result += countSol(coeff,i,end,rhs+coeff[i]);}
        else result += countSol(coeff, i, end, rhs-coeff[i]);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int coeff[]  = {8,-1,8,9};
    int rhs = 19;
    int n = sizeof(coeff)/sizeof(coeff[0]);
    cout << countSol(coeff, 0, n-1, rhs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation about your algorithm besides your code? It is very difficult to understand the raw code. Plus, I guess OP is more curious how, instead of a code ready to run.

Comment: Hey! @YujieZha I have added the explanation to algo.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still a bit confused about step a) - according to my understanding, the variables are non-negative integers, but the coefficients could be negative? And also for the recursion, why could we subtract the RHS?

Comment: I think you meant case 1. I considered the coefficients to be positive because, once the coefficient are negative and the rhs is 0, there can be infinite solutions to the eqn. For example: $1x_1 - 3x_2 = 0$. there are infinity solutions to it.

Comment: sorry, for 1, I meant that if there is one coefficient greater than the RHS, it's variable could still be positive - you could make other coefficients negative so that the equation still holds. And for 2, if say you make a variable 0, how could you subtract the RHS with that coefficient to make the recursion? - it looks to me that for each subtraction of non-zero on the RHS, you changed the original equation.

Comment: @YujieZha thanks for pointing out. Now this code will work for negative coefficients but non zero rhs. For negative rhs eqn we can make the rhs positive and reverse the sign of coefficients, and the code should work fine. If we want to know the values of variables, we can just add up the times we are "subtracting" ( "adding" in case of negative coefficients) the coefficients "from" ( "to" in case of negative coefficients) the rhs.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly @VivekKumarSingh, RHS is the 'c' in an equation of the form `ax + bx +gx = c` yes?

Comment: It's good to have the number of solutions @VivekKumarSingh but I'm actually after an algo that will produce an array of unique solutions.

Comment: @sidewaiise yes 'c' is the rhs. You can get the unique points by writing some extra lines of code.

Comment: You added a condition for negative coefficients. In this case, all integers will be positive. Nice touch but just pointing this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In algebraic geometry, a zero set can sometimes be given by using parametric equations such as the tangent surface of the twisted cubic: $x=t+u$, $y=t^2+u$, and $z=t^3+3tu$. Running over all $u$ and $t$ gives you a drawing of the object.

Implicitization is the problem to provide defining equations for the parametrization. This can be achieved by using Groebner bases. In the above case, take the ideal $I=\langle x-t-u, y-t^2-u, z-t^3-3tu\rangle$ and the lex ordering with $t>u>x>t>z$. Compute a Groebner basis $G$ for the ideal $I$. Then by the elimination thm., the second elimination ideal $I_2=I\cap {\mathbb R}[x,y,z]$ has the Groebner basis $G_2=G\cap{\mathbb R}[x,y,z]$. It contains only one element: $x^3z-(3/4)x^2y^2-(3/2)xyz+y^3+(^/4)z^2$, which is the defining equation for the object in equation.

Not every zero  set has such a parametrization.